Shopify Custom HTML Form to Google Firebase Flutter App Not Working
First, I'm really new at this. I have a very simple HTML form on a custom Shopify page:
<form method="POST" action="https://fb-test.web.app:8080" id="myForm">
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input required="" type="text"> <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>

I have a Flutter app which uses the shelf package to listen for incoming requests. It will eventually write that data to a Firestore DB. This app is hosted on Google cloud and seems to run just fine.
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_echoRequest);

  final server = await serve(handler, 'localhost', 8080);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');

//  runApp(const MyApp());
}


Future<Response> _echoRequest(Request request) async {
  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    final contentType = request.headers['content-type'];
    if (contentType != null && contentType.contains('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')) {
      final form = await request.readAsString();
      final parameters = Uri.splitQueryString(form);
      final name = parameters['name'] ?? 'Unknown';

      // Process the form data here
      print('Name: $name');
      writeFulfillmentRequest(name);


      return Response.ok('Form submitted successfully!');
    }
  }
  return Response.notFound('Not Found');
}

Future<void> writeFulfillmentRequest(String name) async {
  db.collection('quote-request-info').doc;
  if (name != '') {
    await quoteRequestCollection.doc(quoteRequestCollection.id).set({'name': name});
  }


When I enter info and click Submit on the Shopify page form, it spins and eventually returns a This Request Has Timed Out error. And my string isn't written to Firestore. So,

What am I doing wrong?
How can I capture and display the form submit response?

Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Per comments from DazWilkin, I removed the port number and also brought up the Firefox browser dev tools before hitting Submit.
TSS: excluded result:  false content-scripts.js:1:61930
content-tss TSS: hosted page injected fb-test-app.web.app:3:51
content-tss MBTSS: Nonce:  yufinut1v0psa9p356d4v9or6ocy6k2pq944vnosu9kd fb-test-.web.app:3:99
Loading from existing service worker. flutter_bootstrap.js:3:659
Service worker already active. flutter_bootstrap.js:3:907
Injecting <script> tag. Using callback. flutter_bootstrap.js:1:1846
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Stack in the worker:networkRequest@resource://devtools/client/shared/source-map-loader/utils/network-request.js:43:9

Resource URL: https://fb-test-app.web.app/flutter_bootstrap.js
Source Map URL: flutter.js.map

It looks like a 404 error. Do I need to use the port number in the request after all?

One issue is that https://fb-test.web.app:8080 is probably incorrect. If Google is serving a Firebase Function to you (web.app) using HTTPS/TLS (https://) then the port very likely isn't 8080 and probably should be 443 which you can omit as it's the standard port for TLS so ... try https://fb-test.web.app.

By way of explanation, even though your service probably serves content on 8080, when you deploy it to Firebase Functions, Google generates a TLS certificate for you and proxies the traffic from https://{your-function}.web.app to your function service (by default) on 8080.

It's unnecessary to caveat your questions with "I'm new to this". Everyone was new sometime and, if they can't provide you a respectful answer then that's on them, not your unfamiliarity with the product.

Thanks! I no longer get the request timeout - now I get a blank page after submit. The string I sent isn't getting written to Firestore, and it's not like adding print() statements to the Flutter app with the string I sent is going to help since it's running remotely.

If you open your browser's developer tools before you click 'SUBMIT' on the form, you should be able to observe the request and response being made against the Firebase Function on the networks tab (or equivalent). You can also enable Cloud Logging in order to help observe what's going on with the function.

I edited the main text to include the Firefox dev output. Looks like a 404 error?

Are you following a tutorial for this? If so, please add the link to your question. There are several issues. If you open https://fb-test.web.app/  in your browser, the page (404) shows that there's no app behind this page. How are you publishing your Flutter shelf code? Your Flutter shelf code example uses localhost but you cannot use this when you want a server that is accessible from a remote machine (over a network). This is because localhost only provides access from the host machine itself. You would likely want 0.0.0.0 instead. However, let's identify the tutorial you're using..

Yeah, I changed the name of the app here to prevent misuse. If I enter the correct URL into the browser it goes to a blank page. I'm not using a tutorial - I searched for one that uses Flutter, but didn't find anything. I used AI to help write the code I pasted above.

Unable to get this to work. I just tore it all down and wrote a Flutter app hosted on Google Cloud that retrieves the information and stores it in Firestore. I put a URL to that app in in a frame in my Shopify custom page and all is hunky-dory.
